# How can i get my php to work with in a html value attribute that is with in a php block?

Tags: php

I've been stuck on this for a few hours.. How can I get the php with in the html to work appropriately? I need this to work with in a php block.

```
<?php
echo "<input  id=\"abc\"  type=\"text\" placeholder=\"enter abc\"name=\"abc\"  required class=\"form-control\" value=\"<?php if(isset($_POST['abc'])){ echo $_POST['abc']; }?>\" >";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php 
    //here you can use your php
 ?>
 <input id = "abc" type = "text" placeholder ="enter abc" name="abc" required class="form-control" value ="<?php if(isset($_POST['abc'])){ echo $_POST['abc']; }?>">

<?php 
   //here you can use your php
?>
```

You can separate your **HTML and PHP** to avoid too much single and double quote, which usually leads to an error.

Answer (score 0):

if it has to be from the PHP block then try this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['abc']))
{
  $abc = $_POST['abc'];
}
echo "<input  id=\"abc\"  type=\"text\" placeholder=\"enter abc\"name=\"abc\"  required class=\"form-control\" value=\"$abc\" >";
?>
```

Comment: Should also remind to filter input and escape output.

Answer (score 0):

@Hamza Zafeer and @Torchify and @Uttam Kumar Roy gave working solutions.

Just thought i'd give a little explaination.

The php tags (<\?php and ?>) tell the php compiler which parts of the the document are php code that needs to be interpreted and which parts are not (http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php). Everything within the tags will be interpreted as php.

"<\?php" within the the tags the will probably result in a syntax error or undefined constant, unless in a string literal where it will be interpreted as the string "<\?php", as in an echo statement. Within the echo statement "<\input  id=\"abc\"  type=\"text\" placeholder=\"enter abc\"name=\"abc\"  required class=\"form-control\" value="<\?php if(isset($_POST['abc'])){ echo $_POST['abc']; }?>\" >", "<\?php" is just a string.

"?>" within the the tags the will result in the closure of the php code, unless in a string literal where it will be interpreted as the string "<\?php", as in an echo statement. Within the echo statement "<\input  id=\"abc\"  type=\"text\" placeholder=\"enter abc\"name=\"abc\"  required class=\"form-control\" value="<\?php if(isset($_POST['abc'])){ echo $_POST['abc']; }?>\" >", "?>" is just a string.

So within the php tags, the php open tag doesn't need to be called, and the close tag will close the php part of the document.

To echo a variable or results of a function within the tags, just concatenate it to the string, or separate your html and php.